# Elegant way to chain Completables

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

How to chain Completables in a more elegant way? `.toSingleDefault(0)` seems to be hacky

```
Single.just(newGroup)
.flatMapCompletable {
    dao.delete(currentGroup)
}
.toSingleDefault(0)
.flatMapCompletable {
     dao.insert(newGroup)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried before

```
Single.just(newGroup)
    .flatMapCompletable {
        dao.delete(currentGroup)
    }
    .andThen {
        dao.insert(newGroup)
    }
```

and it didn't work without explicit `.subscribe()`, but calling it in `()` like

```
Single.just(newGroup)
    .flatMapCompletable {
        dao.delete(currentGroup)
    }
    .andThen (
        dao.insert(newGroup)
    )
```

will subscribe it automatically